# jquery $.post() does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I know that there a lot of such questions,but I do not find my answer.

Here is the code that works well in all browser. But IE ignore it.

**HTML** (One form for two submissions)

```
<form id="form0" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" 
 onsubmit="sendEmails(); return false;">
              <input id="ef" value="">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function sendEmails() {

        var email = $('#ef').val();

        $('#FormValue_EmailAddress').val(email);
        $('#YMLPValue').val(email);

        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });          

        $.post($("#form1").attr("action"), $("#form1").serialize());
        $.post($("#form2").attr("action"), $("#form2").serialize());
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the error console?

Comment: @Kirill Ivlev ie has an error console?

Comment: Your js is pointing to form1 and form2 not form0. Have you tried http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: Yep. It's called Developer Tools. Click f12 to launch it

Comment: @KirillIvlev yes, I've checked the DevTool. It says 'saveIt' — not definet and pointed to void sting below $('#YMLPValue').val(email);

Comment: @Rob yes, from1 and form2 are filled in with data from form0 and them they submitted. This is ok in ff, chrome and opera.

Comment: If you call `sendEmails()` from the console in IE, does it show any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the issue was with IE security restrictions and adding json to POST. I was helped and my **JS** changed to this variant

```
$.support.cors = true; // force cross-site scripting
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });          

        var request = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $("#form1").attr("action"),
            data: $("#form1").serialize(),
            sync: false,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            crossDomain: true        
        });

        request = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $("#form2").attr("action"),
            data: $("#form2").serialize(),
            sync: false,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            crossDomain: true
        });
```

Thanks for Daniel)